# showModalBottomSheet not showing up under StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StatelessWidget called `PopModalBottomSheet` and I call this in a StatefulWidget. As you can see I have a GestureDetector that has a Text Placeholder `Tap the Image Icon to Select Image(s)`, the problem is that whenever I try to `Tap the Image Icon to Select Image(s)` it redirects me to the selection of images..

The showModalBottomSheet is not showing up whenever I trigger the onTap in GestureDetector..
The sequence that I want is

```
class PopModalBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopModalBottomSheet({super.key, required this.onPressFunction});

  final Function onPressFunction;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // gesture detector for showing the showModalBottomSheet
    return GestureDetector(
    // onTap to show the bottomModalSheet function wherein I store my showModalBottomSheet
      onTap: () => bottomModalSheet(context),
      child: const Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      // this is the text placeholder to trigger the showModalBottomSheet when tapped.
        children: [Icon(Icons.image), Text("Tap the Image Icon to Select Image(s)")],
      ),
    );
  }
  // made a function bottomModalSheet that contains ``showModalBottomSheet``
  void bottomModalSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      isDismissible: false,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25)),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 35.h,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text('Click the button to select images in your gallery.'),
              // onPressed function wherein it will redirect me to my gallery to select images.
                ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressFunction(), child: const Text('Select Image')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is like a sample statefulwidget, but it's just the same with my real statefulwidget.

```
class MyPage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage1({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage1> createState() => _MyPage1State();
}

class _MyPage1State extends State<MyPage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [PopModalBottomSheet(onTapFunction: () {
        // Function here
      })],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: _I call this in a StatefulWidget_ did you mean you put `PopModalBottomSheet` in a widget tree somewhere (like a child of Container or a children of a Row) or did you navigate to this widget?

Comment: ``like a child of Container or a children of a Row``, yes this sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your modal bottom sheet doesn't have enough space for it to appear on the screen. Increasing the height of the `SizedBox` will fix the problem.

```dart
void bottomModalSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    // ...
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 135.h, // increase the height size
        // ...
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[image: Screenshot]